# Can't write to the general pasteboard

Tags: macos, cocoa, sandbox, nsview, nspasteboard

I have a custom NSView that drags a custom core data object. I start the drag process by calling this method:

```
[self dragImage:graphicItem.dragImage at:point offset:CGSizeZero event:theEvent pasteboard:pb source:self slideBack:YES];
```

Before calling the method above I grab the general pasteboard and set a title like this:

```
pb = [NSPasteboard generalPastebaord];
[pb setString:graphicItem.itemDescription forType:(NSString *)kUTTypeText];
```

but immediately after I set the string if I call:

```
[pb stringForType:(NSString *)kUTTypeText]
```

I get nothing.

If I create a pasteboard like this:

```
pb = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:"myPasteBoard"]
```

it does work.
So, I tried getting another standard pasteboard

```
pb = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName: NSDragPboard];
```

But this one too, won't let me write data to it.

I'm calling this method from mouseDragged:(NSEvent *)event;
My application is sandboxed.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the general pasteboard, you have to clear it's contents to prepare it for new items.
From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPasteboard/clearContents):

> Clears the existing contents of the pasteboard, preparing it for new
>   contents. This is the first step in providing data on the pasteboard.

Apple also provides a string constant for plain text string pasteboard contents:`NSPasteboardTypeString`

The following code works, and uses the general pasteboard:

```
NSPasteboard* pasteboard = [NSPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pasteboard clearContents];
[pasteboard setString:@"TestString" forType:NSPasteboardTypeString];
NSLog(@"%@", [pasteboard stringForType:NSPasteboardTypeString]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing before writing to the pasteboard

```
[pb declareTypes:@[(NSString *)kUTTypeText] owner:self]
```